# Vue warn: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am new to vuejs, I am getting following error: 
Error:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <Anonymous>
       <Vcinfo> at resources/assets/js/valuechain/Vcinfo.vue
         <Root>
```

**`Vcinfo.vue`**

```
<template>
    <div id="root">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="navbar-brand">
                <router-link to="/vc">VALUECHAIN</router-link>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><router-link to="/vc/setting_keywords">Keywords Setting</router-link></li>
                <li><router-link to="/vc/keyword_search">Search Keywords</router-link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<style lang="css">
    .navbar {
        margin-top:15px;
    }
</style>
```

**`vc.js`**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vcinfo from './Vcinfo.vue'
import router from './router'

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#vc',
    components: { Vcinfo },
    template: '<vcinfo></vcinfo>',
    router
})
```

**`package.json`**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-14",
    "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.2.0",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "laravel-vue-pagination": "^1.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.4.1",
    "vue": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-js-toggle-button": "^1.1.2",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3",
    "vuejs-datepicker": "^0.9.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "vee-validate": "^2.0.0-rc.8",
    "vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-axios": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-router": "^2.7.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.2",
    "vue2-datatable-component": "^1.1.7"
  }
}
```

I am running above vuejs code inside `laravel` framework. Please suggest what is wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somebody else had exactly the same problem, I wrote an explanation as to what this error means there: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46320757/3122639

In your case, it looks like you are using an older build of laravel with `elixir`, which is now `Laravel Mix`, either way you need to make sure you are aliasing the `runtime + compiler` build in your webpack config. So, from the elixir docs it looks like you will need to create a file called `webpack.conf.js` file in the root of your project with the following:

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
    }
  }
}
```

I would recommend using `webpack 2` on it's own, rather than using `elixir`, which has been deprecated.

Comment: I wrote simple script in html page and trying to run but still getting same error.